# How to fetch specific attribute value in the href URL from response data

Tags: jmeter

I have Response data and in that i want to fetch specific value in the URL got after posting the API using Jmeter HTTP request.

using JSON extract i am able to fetch the href URL which is

CartId=http://ssp4.swblr.skidata.net/ecom/ssp-order/carts/f5146a44-9139-429b-9195-f59e4964b8ed

for this i used JSON extractor and mentioned "JSON Path expressions = $..href" with Match No =1[enter image description here][2]

and i wanted to fetch CartId=http://ssp4.swblr.skidata.net/ecom/ssp-order/carts/**f5146a44-9139-429b-9195-f59e4964b8ed** this Bold marked numeric value
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hE4H.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at these two post processor

- BeanShell PostProcessor
- JSR223 PostProcessor

You can write a bit code to extract the value and store it in a variable and use it where it is required.

Comment: Thanks Acid, and i added Regular expression Extractor and in that for Regular expresion i placed the full Href url with regex as shown below:- "href" : "http://ssp4.swblr.skidata.net/ecom/ssp-order/carts/(.+?)"